# MSFT Echo Bot modified for proactive messages throws exception non-existent Teams Connector v1.0.0

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a simple Microsoft Bot where their EchoBot was modified to send proactive messages.

The problem I face is that the Bot depends on the Teams Connector v0.9.0 (latest stable), but when the Bot gets a POST request to its API endpoint, it throws a FileNotFoundException complaining that Teams Connector v1.0.0 is not found.

One problem is that MSFT does not have a v1.0.0 teams connector and furthermore the project was configured for a v0.9.0 dependency.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?  I tried publishing from both VS2019 Community on Windows and Mac and get the same result.

Here's the POST endpoint I added to the basic MSFT EchoBot template

```
        [Route("api")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] WebServicePrompt prompt)
        {

                var message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
                message.Text = "Hello!";


                var conversationParameters = new ConversationParameters
                {
                    IsGroup = true,
                    ChannelData = new TeamsChannelData
                    {
                        Channel = new ChannelInfo(prompt.ChannelId),
                    },
                    Activity = (Activity)message
                };

                var serviceUrl = "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/";
                MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl, DateTime.Now.AddDays(7));
                var account = new MicrosoftAppCredentials("X", "Y");
                var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceUrl), account);
                var response = await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParameters);

                // Let the caller know proactive messages have been sent
                return new ContentResult()
                {
                    Content = $"Channel ID {prompt.ChannelId}, Response: {response.ToString()}",
                    ContentType = "text/html",
                    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                };

        }
```

Expected Behavior: MSFT Azure should have identified and found the v0.9.0 dependency.  No exception should be thrown and the response should be HTTP 200.

[Project Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H74mt.png)

[Exception Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHhnS.png)

Comment: Which version are you using for Microsoft.Bot.Builder? Could you please update the the packages to 4.5.1?

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT: thanks, I have removed the teams dependency and am using the latest stable Builder release.  I no longer have an issue.

Comment: If your issue is resolved. Please upvote the comment, It will be really helpful for other too.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT: I don't have enough reputation points to upvote yet, :(